# Proving geodesics of a sphere are great circles using calibrating 1-forms.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm attempting to use calibrating 1-forms for a proof of geodesics of a sphere are great circles and am stuck on the last line. My solutions is as follows:  We take the metric $g=\,d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta \,d\phi^2 = \zeta_1^2+\zeta_2^2 $ where $\zeta_1=\,d\theta \; , \; \zeta_2=\sin\theta\,d\phi$. We have that $\,d\zeta_1=0\; , \; \,d\zeta_2 \neq 0$ and also $|\zeta_1|=1$ so $\zeta_1$ is a calibrating 1-form. So geodesics on $S^2$ have length $\int \zeta_1$ according to my notes. If I can show this integral is $2\pi$ then I think this proves that great circles are geodesics but I can't see how to justify the limits being $0$ and $2\pi$. Can someone explain if my proof is correct and if so why the limits should be as I've stated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use $d\theta$ to prove that. Note that $d\theta$ is not a global one form defined on $\mathbb S^2$. It is defined only on $\mathbb S^n\setminus \{\pm p\}$. However, if you are looking for great circle calibrated by this $d\theta$, those great circles has to pass through both $\pm p$.

Indeed, the metric

$$g = d\theta ^2 + \sin\theta^2 d\phi^2$$

is the expression under geodesic polar coordinate. Instead of using calibration, you can using check directly that $\phi = C$ gives you a geodesic.